# C struct initialization with pointer

Tags: c

I am kind of new to C and I cannot figure out why the following code is not working:

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t* b;
} test_struct;

test_struct test = {
    .a = 50,
    .b = {62, 33}
};
```

If I do this instead, it works:

```
int temp[] = {62, 33};

test_struct test = {
    .a = 50,
    .b = temp
};
```

Comment: What do you expect the second code to set the value of `b` to? A pointer to what exactly? In the second code, it's clear, it points to `temp`. What should the first code make `b` point to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `b` member is not an array but a pointer.  So when you attempt to initialize like this:

```
test_struct test = {
    .a = 50,
    .b = {62, 33}
};
```

You're setting `test.b` to the value 62 converted to a pointer, with the extra initializer discarded.

The second case works because you're initializing the `b` member with `temp` which is an `int` array which decays to a pointer to an `int` to match the type of the member `b`.

You could also do something like this and it would work:

```
test_struct test = {
    .a = 50,
    .b = (int []){62, 33}
};
```

However, the pointer to the compound literal will only be valid in the scope it was declared.  So if you defined this struct inside of a function and returned a copy of it, the pointer would no longer be valid.

Comment: What's the lifetime of that inner `.b` value in the second example? Is it necessary to use a `static` variable?

Comment: @tadman The lifetime of a compound literal is that of its enclosing scope.  So if `test` is declared at file scope then the compound literal has full program lifetime.

Comment: For sure, I just mean the context of where this code is used is relevant. Put this in a function and you're in for a *surprise*. It's worth mentioning as that kind of thing can trip you up if you're not expecting it.